# Create Service which calls Rest-APIs (google, flickr) and responds in XML

Tags: xml, api, rest, service

I want to write a Service which can be called from Anywhere with query-terms. The service then makes calls to Google API, FlickR API (and some more maybe) to find images based on the query-terms. The found images (URLs) then should be returned to the invoker in XML-Format.

What would be the easiest/most efficient way to write such a service? right now i am at the start of this and dont know, yet, which technology to use (language, framework, ..). basically, i am open to everything.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of people visiting your site or there will be lots of calls then go with WCF.
It will give you lots of flexibility.

However if your calls would be limited go with normal webservices.